# How to add JSON object into attribute of an element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying almost for an hour to fix the problem of adding JSON object into an attribute of an element using this code in order to play some video:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({"techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" });
$('#popup-companyPitch').html('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360" data-setup="'+json+'"></video>');
```

I have the same thing in another part of my site where I use php to grab the data from db and it just works perfectly fine:

```
<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "<?php echo $obj->video_url;?>" }'></video>
```

I don't know why am I not able to make it work for the first case using jquery.

Thnx

Comment: $('#popup-companyPitch').data('setup', json);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the escaping of the quotes in the attributes so

If you want to set it as an attribute itself

```
var json = JSON.stringify({"techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" });
var $el = $('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360"></video>').attr('data-setup', json);
$('#popup-companyPitch').html($el);
```

If you want to set it just as an data property

```
var json = {"techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" };
var $el = $('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360"></video>').data('setup', json);
$('#popup-companyPitch').html($el);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the data property. Good call. Also for other reasons, probably best way when dealing with that much data instead of an attribute. Attributes not really meant for that.

Comment: not working... on the inspect element when I look ur code generates this:{&quot;techOrder&quot;:[&quot;youtube&quot;],&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY&quot;}

Comment: That is how the valid attribute value should look like as it has to escape the quotes

Comment: were u the first one who answered? so i can add ur answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code. its better to add big 'data-' using `data()` function

```
var json = JSON.stringify({"techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" });
video_element= $('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360"></video>');
   vide_element.attr('data-setup', json); //if you want visible attribute you can use vide_element.attr('data-setup', json)

$('#popup-companyPitch').append(video_element);
```

Comment: this code is not working too... it doesnt even add the setup attribute into the element when i check into the inspect element in chrome...

Comment: jquery does not add any attribute that you can see in inspector

Comment: if you want visible attribute you can use vide_element.attr('data-setup', json);

Comment: Actually your code seems good and it generates the new attribute fine, but still my video is not playing... strange , well i can accept this answer as it did what I was expecting, maybe i have some other problem with the player... thnx